# Pass vector/lists to an executable frompython

Tags: python, matlab, exe

I have a Matlab `.EXE` file which calls a function `BlendingFacialFeatures()`.

This function needs source vertices `V_S` and target vertices `V_T` as a list. As the output, it returns a list of vertices as well.

Now I am trying to call this `.EXE` file from python. I tried:

```
arg = "D:\\Face_Morphing\\Codes\\Exe\\V02\\exe\\BlendingFacialFeatures.exe"
result = subprocess.call([arg , V_S , V_T])
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I was wondering how I can pass my vectors/lists directly to the Matlab `.EXE` file. Is it even possible?

Comment: what do your variables `V_S` and `V_T` look like?

Comment: Ther are lists of vertex positions, so if I print them they are going to be sth like: [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...,[xn,yn,zn]]